# Convert literal text/string to timestamp

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I imported data from a marketing source in my db and it changed the format of the timestamp.

This is how the timestamp stored in string/text format appears - 20220725115427 ---1

This is what this string actually means if you manually space it out - 2022-07-25 11:54:27 ---2

How do I go from 1 to 2? I want 2 in timestamp format.

Any help is appreciated.

I'm on Amazon Redshift Database - redshift SQL

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html) function?

Usage:

```
SELECT '20220725115427' AS str, TO_TIMESTAMP('20220725115427', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AS ts;
```

Please see this for [forammting reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html).